# Unable to get the DocuSign API integrator key

Tags: docusignapi

I am evaluating the DocuSign API, but unable to get the integrator key. Is there any way to get the integrator key?

Currently I am using DocuSign trial version.

Below are the steps followed:

1. Logged into this link “https://app.docusign.com/home”
2. Clicked on drop down at the top right corner and clicked on "Go To Admin"
3. Navigated to "Api and Keys" in "Integration".  It asked to “log in” again to manage integrator keys, Below is the screen shot.
   ![enter image description here][1]
4. After clicked on log in, it is redirected to “Billing and Usage” page. Below is the screen shot.
   ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign has a full demo environment which is a mirror of the live production system and allows for you to test and integrate the APIs.  To do so you need to create a developer sandbox (they are free) and create an Integrator Key through the Admin menu of your sandbox - which is the only place the keys can be created - then promote that key to your live production account.

You can create your developer sandbox here:  https://secure.docusign.com/signup/develop

To login to your sandbox:  https://account-d.docusign.com/#/web/login

Once you've created an Integrator Key and you are ready to access production API endpoints follow these steps:

1. Run 20 or more error-free transactions that comply with API rules and limits under your Integrator Key.
2. Purchase an [API plan](https://secure.docusign.com/developer) (sounds like you already created your live account)
3. Make sure you have Admin priveleges to your live production account as they are required to link the Integrator Key.
4. Fill out the Go Live form to promote your Integrator Key.

You can access the form through the [Go Live](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live) section of the Developer Center.